# Sqlite and TCheckBox in C++Builder FMX

Tags: c++builder

I have created a sqlite table

`create table1(int_field integer,...)`

The form has a TCheckBox component.
I bound the field int_field to CheckBox1 using LiveBindings.
How to convert the state value CheckBox1->IsChecked=true/false to the field value int_field=1/0.  No code.

Comment: Malcolm Groves wrote a blog post about this very topic: [LiveBindings : How to treat an Integer field as a Boolean?](http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=1490)